# What is the actual record of the property's lot size in sqft?

Tags: data-request, postal-code

I have a list of US Addresses. I am trying to find the 'lot size' of each address. is there any database I can go find this? or at least some data that gives me the average lot size by zip code?

Comment: I know one exists for the City of Albuquerque (it has the polygons describing each lot), so I'd try contacting various state and city agencies, but I'm guessing this is hit and miss. Ultimately, property "platting" is done at the county level, but I'm not sure how many counties have this information available online and/or if it's in a GIS usable form.